# Quartz thread pool replace with Pooled Executor Service

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there a Quartz Thread Pool Implementation (http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/quartz/quartz-2.0.2/org/quartz/spi/ThreadPool.java.html)  with Pooled Executor Service ?  instead of using SimpleThreadPool which is using work thread model.

Thanks,

BMIS13

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ConcurrentTaskExecutor and/or ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html (look at the 25.2.1 section)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something similiar some time ago [ExecutorThreadPool](https://gist.github.com/jarek-przygodzki/7991992)